# Getting previous documents using firestore pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore database to store my crypto trades. Since there are a lot of them, I have to load them using the `.limit(numberOfTrades)` query.

My query: `const tradesRef = firebase.firestore().collection("trades").limit(15);`

Inside my useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
      tradesRef
        .where("type", "==", "fiveMinutes")
        .get()
        .then((collections) => {
          const tradesData = collections.docs.map((trade) => trade.data());
          const lastDoc = collections.docs[collections.docs.length - 1];
          setTrades(tradesData);
          setLastTrades(lastDoc);
        });
    
    setDataLoading(false);
  }, [filter]);
```

However, I do need pagination in order to load the next set of trades. The pagination of next is already implemented and fairly simple. This is the function I am using for next page:

```
const fetchMore = () => {
    tradesRef
      .startAfter(lastTrades)
      .get()
      .then((collections) => {
        const tradesData = collections.docs.map((trade) => trade.data());
        const lastDoc = collections.docs[collections.docs.length - 1];
        setTrades(tradesData);
        setLastTrades(lastDoc);
      });
  }
```

Now I am trying to figure out how to implement a previous page query that gets the previous 12 trades. I have researched and implemented a few queries but I am not even close to solving the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to paginate backwards, you need to use a combination of:

```
.endBefore(firstItemOnNextPage)
.limitToLast(12)
```

So `firstItemOnNextPage` is the first item on page N+1, where you're paginating backwards from. And you're then asking for the last 12 items before that anchor item.

Comment: How do I set the `firstItemOnNextPage`?

Comment: The same as you set `lastDoc`/`lastTrades` in your current code: you have to remember the `firstItemOnNextPage` when you are on that page, so that you can use it to load the page before it.